# Is there any way to use multiple versions of Bootstrap in React without any trouble?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Suppose, I import two versions of Bootstrap (Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap 4) on two different components in a React application. Let's say, they are `<App/>` (Bootstrap 3) and `<Test/>` (Bootstrap 4). Initially, I am on the `<App/>` component. Now, if I navigate to `<Test/>` component which loads and imports Bootstrap 4, will Bootstrap 3 on `<App/>` component be removed? Or it will still load.

Comment: Make it Component based css.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting question.  The answer depends on how you used `Bootstrap` for those two components `Test` and `App`.

Normally people just import the bootstrap css, obviously this won't work simply because I guess even `Bootstrap3` and `4` conflicts with each other.

But if you take snippet of `3` or `4` and use it locally inside the component via `styled-component` or any css in js approach. It'll work in theory.

In practice, it carries other issues, because `Bootstrap` depends on lots of internal utility functions, just to get it spin requires lots of work, which might not worth it if you just want to use it to power one component.

I'll stop here, you'll find quite a bit library which tries to solve this problem, name a few `material-ui`, `reactstrap`. Simply search `Bootstrap react` will give you quite something.